# limit field.Spinner data

Tags: extjs, spinner, store

Spinner and Store (store have field: 'price')

```
Ext.define('TPL.store.Price', {
    fields: [
    {name: 'price', type: 'string'},

],
proxy: {
type: 'ajax',
url: '/author/price"',
reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        successProperty: 'success'
}}});
```

and i am want in my field.Spinner  show only data from  store 'Price'. I have two function onSpinUp and onSpinDown that functions must +1 or -1  Price, but no more and no less than than have Store 'Price'

```
 spinner = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Spinner', {
            step: 1,
            width: 100,
            height: 10
              onSpinUp: function() { }
              onSpinDown: function() { };
```

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want to spin between the values in your store, or bound the max and min of the spinner by the max/min values in your store.   For example, if you have values: [2,4,6] in your store, and a value of 2 displayed on the spinner, if you spin up, do you want to display 3 or 4?

Comment: so, given values of [2,4,6] in your store, do you want to go 2 -> 3, or 2 -> 4 on the display?

Comment: i am want if my store have values of [2,4,6], in Spinner i am display only this values: [2,4,6]. And if i am display 4, and onSpinUp   display "6", onSpinDown display "2".